# How do I replace quotes with square brackets in a string

Tags: php, regex

I have this string `'My String'` with square brackets eg `[My String]`.

At the moment I can only get the string like:

`$re = '/'([^']+)'/';
$str = "'My String'";
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);`

How can I get replace the qoutes using `preg_replace()`

Comment: Why not use `preg_replace` in the first place? Also, you should form string literals correctly.

Comment: The issue I have is how to use `preg_replace` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to replace '' with []:

```
<?php

$string = "blabla'My String'blabla";
echo preg_replace("/([^']*)'([^']+)'([^']*)/", '$1[$2]$3', $string);
// Output will be "blabla[My String]blabla"
```

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is a core php function that replace a pattern in a string

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not working. Problem is I do not know how the string is formated. it can be `'blabla' bla 'b' bla` so I need braket where the string has qoutes

Comment: With this code  `'blabla' bla 'b' bla` will be transformed to `[blabla] bla [b] bla` . Can you give me the expected output?

Comment: This just ads the bracket on the first and last quote of  the string

Comment: i.e [blabla bla b] bl

Comment: Thanks man for pointing me in the rite direction, this worked `preg_replace("/([^'])'([^']+)'([^'])/", '$1[$2]$3', $string);`